# problema con promesas javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de realizar unos ejercicios de nodeschool sobre las promesas en Javascript. Consigo realizar medio ejercicio, pero me pide más cosas y no entiendo muy bien lo que me pide, ando un poco perdido en callbacks y promesas y me gustaria entender la logica. Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradeceria.
El enunciado del ejercicio es este:
Crear una promesa que después de un retraso de 300ms, rechace con un objeto Error.
El objeto Error debe construirse con el parámetro '¡Rechazado!', que es el mensaje textual del error.
Crear una función onReject para imprimir el mensaje de error usando console.log. Pase a esta función como un manejador de rechazo al método then de su promesa.
Como repaso de la última lección, la función then de una promesa toma dos callbacks:
la primera para ser llamada cuando la promesa se cumple y la segunda cuando la
promesa es rechazada.

El error que me da el programa es este.
✓ El resultado concuerda con lo esperado
✓ Constructor de promesas utilizado
✗ Método reject no utilizado con un objeto de Error
✗ ¡Casi lo logras! Agregaste un manejador en caso de éxito en vez de en caso de falla a la promesa, en la llamada a `.then`.
Y este mi ejercicio. Como veis las dos ultimas salen con una x, lo que significa que el ejercicio no esta completado. Gracias por vuestra ayuda

```
var promise = new Promise (function(fulfill, reject){
    setTimeout(()=>{       
        onReject('REJECTED!')
    },300);
});

function onReject (error) {
    
    console.log(error);
  }
promise
.then(value => console.log(value))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Creo que te está indicando que no utilizaste un objeto `Error` (devuelves un `string`, no un `Error`) y creo que pide que uses la callback de error del método `then()`, dicho método acepta dos parámetros, el primero para cuando va bien y el segundo para cuando falla: `promise.then((value) => console.log(value), (err) => console.log(err));`. Al menos eso entiendo con el segundo error que te marcó. Tienes más info de esto en la [documentación de `Promise` de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Gracias Benito, no he podido solucionar mi problema, realmente me gustaria sacarlo, más que nada para acabar de entenderlo, no se porque el ejercicio me pone una funcion en medio y cual seria su utilidad. Se que las promesas y callbacks cuestan un poco y trato de trabajar con ello hasta que mi cabeza ate todos los cabos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que lo que se te pide en tu ejercicio es que retornes el metodo `reject()`, de las promesas, no que hagas una `function onReject(error)`, recuerda que en las promesas se encuentra en `resolve()`; te dejo una [referencia](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) si es satisfactoria y el `reject()` si falla, y por lo que veo solo te pide hacer la función ´reject´ dentro del `setTimeout`; a mi parecer debería ser así:

```
  const promesa = new Promise( (resolve, reject)=>{
     setTimeout(()=>{
        
        /*
        reject( ()=>{
           aca retornas lo que quieras...
           return 'fallo';
        });
        //o asi
        reject( ()=> 'fallo');
        */
        //y si buscas capturar un error
       reject(  new Error(onReject( '¡Rechazado!' )) );

    },300);
  });

  function onReject( parametro ){

     
     /* o podria ser
        console.log( parametro );
     */
      return parametro;
  }

  promesa.then( resp=> console.log( resp ) )
     //esta linea es opcional...
    //.then(data => console.log( data ))
    .catch( error => console.log( error ) );
```

Saludos.

Comment: Bueno, la function onReject me la pide en el ejercicio. Ahora probando cosas he conseguido que me confirme la tercera opcion, pero la primera se me ha tachado. Estoy dandole a la página que me has enviado y es la explicacion más clara que he encontrado sobre las promesas. Gracias

Comment: ok solo crea la función y en el reject la llamas, ya actualice la respuesta

Comment: Estamos cerca y ya estoy entendiendo la logica, pero me sigue dando un resultado que no es correcto. Y eso que a tu código no le veo ningun fallo. Si que es verdad que la function onReject recibe un parametro de (error) y creo que por ahi tiene que estar el fallo. Pero la resolucion de este ejercecicio me esta ayudando a entender muchas cosas. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: ok veo que dice retorna la respuesta en un log del parametro, en ese caso si puedes seguir la logica de tu codigo. volvi a actualizar.

Comment: Ya lo probe y me sigue sin funcionar, pero tu codigo es correcto, solo que no resuelve mi ejercicio completamente. Pero me ha ayudado mucho a entender la lógica de las promesas. Asi que doy la respuesta como correcta. Gracias por tu interes y tu ayuda.